# "addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask" returns `null`

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to monitor global events so, I tried adding the global monitor. However, I couldn't get any information from this monitor. It gets activated on a event but returns `NULL`.

```
    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask) handler:^(NSEvent *incomingEvent){
NSLog(@"Window Number :%@",[[incomingEvent window] windowNumber]);
}];
```

This code is in `(id)init` method in the program. Whenever I click a window or cause an event I get my NSLOG message with NULL as the window info.
Sample Output is as follows:

```
Window Number: (null)
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Could anyone please explain me?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. The problem I faced was due to

```
NSLog(@"Window Number :%@",[[incomingEvent window] windowNumber]);
```

If you want to display the details of the window you clicked, use `CGWindow.h` routines as described in the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4704158/1249876

Though, logically, `windowNumber` is a method of the `NSWindow` Class, in this case it doesn't return any output, which is a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: `windowNumber` seams to return a `NSInteger` so you should not use the `%@` format string which require an object. Why it outputs as `(null)` is probably because `windowNumber` returns 0 which will be interpreted as NULL pointer.